# I'm having trouble trying to select a <textarea>

Tags: css, html, textarea

HI,

Any ideas why I can't highlight the text in the "blurbedit" or "headlineblack" divs?

I think I did a bit of sloppy coding to get the footer divs to line up horizontally, but that then meant that the top divs can't be selected, which isn't great when one of them is an input field!

check out this example to see what I mean: www.gherkin.co.nz/ff/textarea.html

You can select the text of the three divs at the bottom, but not the ones at the top.

I'm sure it's a very obvious thing but I'm having a hard time trying to spot it...

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="headlinered">Homepage Blurb:</div>
    <div class="home_headline_edit">


    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="
    1">
    <textarea name="blurb" cols="40" rows="10" class="box" id="blurbedit">

blurb edit content
    </textarea>
    <input name="update1" type="submit" class="box" id="editbutton" value="Update Article"></form>
    </div>
    <div class="header2cms">

    <p class="headlineblack">

    headline content
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="headlinered">Footer:</div>

    <div style="height:300px;">
      <div class="footer">
        <p class="bodyblack">
       footer content

    </p>
      </div>


    <div>


    <form method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="
    1">
    <textarea name="footer" cols="30" rows="10" class="box" id="footeredit">
footer edit content
    </textarea><br />
    <input name="update2" type="submit" class="box" id="footerbutton" value="Update Article"></form>
    </div>

    <div class="footerhelp">
    (footer help)

    </div>
    </div>

    </div>
```

and here is the css:

```
.footerhelp{
    width: 300px;
    position: relative;
    left: 475px;
    margin-top:60px;
    top: -270px;
    overflow: hidden;

}
.footer {
    width: 170px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position:absolute;
}
#blurbedit{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:0.8em;
    border: none;
    background:#CCC;
    color:#666;
    padding:10px;
}
#footeredit{
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:0.8em;
    border: none;
    background:#CCC;
    color:#666;
    padding:10px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 190px;
    top: 0px;
}
.headlinered {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 140%;
    color: #991200;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.headlineblack {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1.7em;
    line-height: 140%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    width:455px;
}
.home_headline_edit{
    float:left;
    width: 360px;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.container {
    width: 835px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
}
.header2cms {
    width: 455px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
.bodyblack {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: .7em;
    line-height: 140%;
    color: #000000;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I changed the color attribute of the #blurbedit rule to yellow, and I can clearly see that it is colored correctly.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain it very well. I will post a link to the page in a minute, and you will see what I mean

Comment: aha...different behavior when comparing IE 7 to FireFox 3.5 and Google Chrome.  I take it you're using one of the latter browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Would you believe that it's a combination of the `float: left` and `position: relative` settings of your `.home_headline_edit` and `.container` rules that is causing this issue?

Removing the `position: relative` rule seems to work while retaining the visual style of the page.

Smells like a browser bug...but I can't seem to reproduce it with a trimmed down page.

Comment: YUSS! That is a weird bug. any idea how to remove the float but keep the same layout? It all goes pearshaped when the float is removed...

Comment: ...on a serious note though.  I did create a very basic page that had a DIV.container element with an enclosed TEXTAREA.  I couldn't replicate this problem in that basic format.  So we found our goose, so to speak...

Comment: @unknown: as a side note, the HTML markup I grabbed off of the URL in the OP has two sets of html and meta tags, an orphaned </div> close tag, and input element values are on multiple lines.  This doesn't break browsers' ability to render the pages, but it couldn't hurt to fix these issues and make your page(s) more XHTML-compliant.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use hammer.js ? 
Because Hammer.js binds the "selectstart" event to various elements.
At least that's a case i've had.